# How to get a tight div when heights differ?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a series of `div` aligned in a row with `flexbox`. Their heights differ and the largest one sets a common height for all the `div`. An example is given in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/x4wtpp3v/):

[image]

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="big">
    hello
  </div>
  <div>
    bonjour
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-color: gray;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}

.big {
  height: 100px;
}
```

The box with "hello" is set to `100px` and the natural height of the one with "bonjour" is much smaller. It however inherits the height of its bigger neighbour.

**How can I have heights driven by the contents rather than by the maximum size of divs within a series of boxes aligned next to each others?**

Comment: I´m not sure if this is what you want https://jsfiddle.net/fgr1dcct/

Comment: @DavidRosa: exactly, but using `flexbox` (which I need for general positionning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `align-items: flex-start;` to parent div.

```
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-color: gray;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  align-items: flex-start; // Here
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4wtpp3v/3/)**

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for.